# When defining which subproperty in EF mapping via Fluent API should be ignored, an ArgumentException is thrown

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I created a mapping in the **Entity Framework** via **Fluent API**, but when defining that a sub-property should be ignored, the exception below is thrown:

> **System.ArgumentException:** 'The expression 'x =>
>   x.PaisCompleto.Descricao' is not a valid property expression. The
>   expression should represent a simple property access: 't =>
>   t.MyProperty'.'

**Mapeamento**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new EnderecoMap());
    }
}

public class EnderecoMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Endereco>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Endereco> builder)
    {
        builder
            .OwnsOne(g => g.PaisCompleto, pais => {

                pais
                    .Property(c => c.Codigo)
                    .HasColumnName("PaisCodigo")
                    .HasColumnType("varchar(5)");
            });
        builder.Ignore(x => x.PaisCompleto.Descricao);// throw exception

        builder
            .OwnsOne(g => g.CidadeCompleto, cidade => {

                cidade
                    .Property(c => c.Codigo)
                    .HasColumnName("CidadeCodigo")
                    .HasColumnType("varchar(7)");
            });
        builder.Ignore(x => x.CidadeCompleto.Descricao);// throw exception
    }    
}
```

**Entidades Mapeadas**

```
public abstract class Endereco
{
    public DtoConceito<string> CidadeCompleto { get; set; }
    public string CEP { get; set; }
}

public class DtoConceito<T>
{    
    public T Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: PaisCompleto and CidadeCompleto do map to entity types. Ignore the properties in the entity configuration of these types.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro how I create a map to DtoConceito<T> that have a generics <T>?

Comment: @DevilSuichiro when I create DtoConceitoMap<string> ignoring "Descricao" attribute, is throw that exception: "System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'DtoConceito<string>' cannot be added to the model because a weak entity type with the same name already exists." on  builder.ApplyConfiguration(new DtoConceitoMap<string>());

Comment: @Ricardo `Ignore` the property of an owned entity the same way you define column name / type - via `pais` and `cidade` variables inside `OwnsOne`, e.g. `cidade.Ignore(c => c.Descricao);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relationships in an Entity should only reflect entities, not DTOs or non-entity classes. If you really want a non-entity class to be referenced in an entity, then the whole non-entity reference should be flagged as `NotMapped`.

EF does support inheritance but I'd avoid it unless necessary. AFAIK the support in EF Core is still somewhat limited based on table structures you can use with it.

```
public class Endereco
{
    public virtual Conceito CidadeCompleto { get; set; }
    public string CEP { get; set; }
}

// If Conceito is a table...
public class Conceito
{    
    [Key]
    public string Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
}
```

then map the Conceito...

```
    builder
        .OwnsOne(g => g.CidadeCompleto)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForgeignKey("CidadeCodigo"); // Shadow property for the FK Code.
```

This expects that the Endereco has a FK called "CidadeCompleto" which points to a CidadeCodigo table.

If a Endereco has a string for a CidadeCompleto which does not have a supporting table, or is part of a separate lookup table with no direct FK and you just want a specific DTO to represent that code and a description loaded separately then I would recommend having the entity map the column that is there, and manage the DTO reference separately in the view model rather than in the entity.

When you load a Endereco and want to pass a DTO for an associated lookup value (Code + Description) use the CidadeCompleto code to look up the appropriate DTO and populate it in the view model for the view that needs the code & description. The entity should reflect the data as it is in the database. The view models and DTOs reflect what you want the view/consumer to see. Look to keep those two concerns separate rather than mixing view-specific fields & structures with the data representation.